# Jenkins with Stylecop and Fxcop

Tags: jenkins

I have set up Jenkins on windows 2008 r2 environment and its working fine except violations report is not loading correctly it does not shows the code files neither for fxcop and stylecop only graphs are available.

Jenkins Version : 1.539

StylecopCmd     : 0.2.1.0

Fxcop           : 1.36

Violations      : 0.7.11

Comment: We also use Jenkins + StyleCop + FXCop and we can click the graphs to get more informations (which line of code the error occur). Did you try to click on the graphs?

Comment: As far as I rember we use 'Violations Plugin' for showing FxCop- und StyleCop-Reports.

Comment: I used the same but its not showing the file report

Comment: Ok. Strange. To get more in detail I post an answer with some screenshots. Maybe it is easier to compare and hopefully we will find the difference.

Comment: @Micha ,user2822319 Still I am having this issue , Guys did u got any solution for this .

Comment: @Midhun: Didn't know if the error still exist.

Comment: Issue is still there

Answer (score 0):

For this case we use **Violations Plugin**.

It is configurable in job-config ...

[image]

... it generates a nice chart (on the job-overview-page), which is clickable ...

[image]

... if you click the chat you get a report. The report can also show you in which code file the violation occurs (including code)

[image]

Comment: up to your last screen shot everything works but when I click on code file it loads an empty page

Comment: Ok, for style cop we have also only blank pages. FxCop for C# und VB showes code.